# Module dependencies

Tags: python, dependencies, ray

I am using *ray* library of python but I got an error even if I have the mentioned file.
The error is the following:

> FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\boezi\PycharmProjects\AWSDeepRacerChallenge\env\lib\site-packages\ray_raylet.pyd' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

pip did not recognize the library, therefore I downloaded the wheel archive, I extracted it and I put the content in the site-packages folder of my virtual environment.
The package is recognized and I can use automatic filliing with my IDE but I have the aforementioned problem.

Comment: if you get `wheel` then you should use `pip` to install it.

Comment: it may need some C/C++ libraries which you may have to install manually. You should check in documentation if it has some external dependencies

Comment: you may check if there is `ray_raylet.py` - to see source code and see what C/C++ libraries it may need.